# I am not able to add android platform for ionic

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework

I start working on IONIC. When I add android to project. I am getting below error.

> 1. I have installed Android Studio and pointed SDK (Latest versions)
> 2. updated Cordova and IONIC
> 3. JAVA version is 1.8.0.111

But still I am getting below error, Please anyone suggest me what I can do to fix this issue.

> C:\shainfotech\abhayaV2>cordova platform add android --save Adding
>   android project... Creating Cordova project for the Android platform:
>           Path: platforms\android
>           Package: com.ionicframework.abhayav2195873
>           Name: abhayaV2
>           Activity: MainActivity
>           Android target: android-24 Subproject Path: CordovaLib Android project created with cordova-android@6.0.0 Installing
>   "cordova-plugin-console" for android
>   ANDROID_HOME=C:\Users\satyagvns\AppData\Local\Android\sdk
>   JAVA_HOME=C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.8.0_111 Failed to install
>   'cordova-plugin-console':CordovaError: Requirements check failed for
>   JDK 1.8 or greater
>       at C:\shainfotech\abhayaV2\platforms\android\cordova\lib\check_reqs.js:278:19
>       at _fulfilled (C:\shainfotech\abhayaV2\platforms\android\cordova\node_modules\q\q.js:834:54)
>       at self.promiseDispatch.done (C:\shainfotech\abhayaV2\platforms\android\cordova\node_modules\q\q.js:863:30)
>       at Promise.promise.promiseDispatch (C:\shainfotech\abhayaV2\platforms\android\cordova\node_modules\q\q.js:796:13)
>       at C:\shainfotech\abhayaV2\platforms\android\cordova\node_modules\q\q.js:604:44
>       at runSingle (C:\shainfotech\abhayaV2\platforms\android\cordova\node_modules\q\q.js:137:13)
>       at flush (C:\shainfotech\abhayaV2\platforms\android\cordova\node_modules\q\q.js:125:13)
>       at _combinedTickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:67:7)
>       at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:98:9)

```
Error: Requirements check failed for JDK 1.8 or greater
```

Please help me to fix this issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, I am able to resolve issue. I have installed too many JDKs in my system. I uninstalled all versions and installed only JDK 1.8. Reboot my system.

1. I faced one more problem like, license folder missing in my sdk
2. Updated my Android studio with SDK 24 until license folder placed in sdk folder.
3. ionic platform rm android
4. ionic platform add android

It works for me.

Thank you for your support.

Answer (score 2):

You didn't set your path correctly. set

> JAVA_HOME to the 1.8 JRE location

Refer following link https://forum.ionicframework.com/t/error-requirements-check-failed-for-jdk-1-8-or-greater/68734/8

Comment: Thanks for your help @Anuj. But still I am getting the same error.

Comment: Did you check your path properly ?

Comment: Did that solution fixed your issue?

Answer (score 0):

Removing different versions of JDK would have fixed the issue in your case. But you can still make it work even with having multiple versions of jdk.

In my case I made it work by mentioning only the required JDK's path in the 'path' environment variable. With this setting I could make it work by having multiple versions of JDKs for different project developments